# There exists a countable set of mutually orthogonal trigonometric functions which form a basis for $L^2(T)$. Proof?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, trigonometric-series

Evidently, this fact (for real or complex valued functions) is usually taken "for-granted" in derivations of Fourier series/transform, taking $\{e^{inx}|n\in\mathbf Z\}$ as the set of basis vectors.

My hope is to find proof for this. (preferably "simple", but any valid proof will do :).

Thanks.

Comment: Not every countable set of mutually orthogonal trigonometrix functions forms a basis for square integrable fucntion space. And in fact I doubt countable for the general case.

Comment: Seconding Hagen von Eitzen, I believe that you are referring to the space $L^2(\mathbb{T})$ of square integrable *and periodic* functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the Hilbert space you are referring to is $L^2(\mathbb{T})$, the space of square integrable and $2\pi$-periodic functions. In this case the *trigonometric system* 
$$\left\{\frac{e^{i n x}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\ :\ n\in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$$
forms an orthonormal basis. The proof  of this comprises of two parts: the first is showing that the system is orthonormal, which is a straightforward check, and the second is showing that it is complete$^{[1]}$, which is more involved. As far as I know, there are at least three ways of proving this:

1. You can prove this directly, as in Rudin R&CA, 3rd edition, §4.24. You do not need any particular prerequisite, but the proof is clearer if you know something about convolutions.
2. You can use Stone-Weierstrass's theorem which shows that the trigonometric system is complete in $C(\mathbb{T})$, from which you infer completeness in $L^2(\mathbb{T})$ by a simple embedding argument.
3. You can use Sturm-Liouville's theory or Hilbert-Schmidt's theorem on compact operators and observe that the trigonometric system is exactly the set of normalized eigenfunctions of the following boundary-value problem: $$\begin{cases} \frac{du}{dx}= i\lambda u, & x\in (0, 2\pi) \\ u(0)=u(2\pi) \end{cases}$$ (See Coddington-Levinson's book on ordinary differential equations, chapter "Self-adjoint problems on finite intervals").

Either approach has its advantages and disadvantages.

---

$^{[1]}$ Definition: If $S$ is a subset of a Banach space $X$, then it is said to be *complete* if its linear span is dense in $X$. Warning: This terminology is not universally accepted.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'd never have expected all this information on this topic! I really appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome! Beware that I had forgotten to write the $\lambda$ in the eigenvalue equation above. Without that it made no sense.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, although it was not REALLY necessary.. You can't misinterpret an $O[V]=i\lambda V$ pattern, even if It's noisy.. Like an over simplified Captcha.. :)

Comment: It's not really a question about Math so this is the place to ask it: Do you think/know/believe that Fourier himself had proof for this? Or maybe it was just intuitively obvious from his point of view? (You have to admit that even without proof, a little bit of spatial imagination/perception leaves little doubt on whether the set discussed above is in fact a basis of the space discussed above)

Comment: This has been discussed a lot. It is known that Fourier's original constructions do not match today's standards for a rigorous proof, and in fact they originated much controversy at his time, too. I am no expert, but I believe that he stated something like: "every periodic function can be decomposed as a sum of sines and cosines".